# Linux Bash OR operator in IF statement didn't work as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let say there are 2 hosts with different naming convention ...

`ab_01` and `ab_cd`

I would like to make sure their naming convention comply with certain standard.

So, I've written simple script to test it.

```
wolf@linux:~$ host='ab_01'

wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[a-z][a-z] ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False

wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9] ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
```

It works!

Next step is to combine these 2 regex with OR operator in Shell which is `||`

```
if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[a-z][a-z] || $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9] ]];
then
    echo True
else
    echo False
fi
```

Let's test it

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo $host
ab_01
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[a-z][a-z] || $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9] ]];
> then
>     echo True
> else
>     echo False
> fi
True
wolf@linux:~$
```

It works with both `ab_01` and `ab_cd`.

However, when I adding more character to the hostnames, I'm still getting True when it should be False.

Let's test this with `host='ab_0123'` and `host='ab_cdef'`

```
wolf@linux:~$ host='ab_0123'
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[a-z][a-z] || $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9] ]];
> then
>     echo True
> else
>     echo False
> fi
True
wolf@linux:~$
```

Another test also shows True instead of False

```
wolf@linux:~$ host='ab_cdef'
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[a-z][a-z] || $host =~ [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9] ]];
> then
>     echo True
> else
>     echo False
> fi
True
wolf@linux:~$
```

What's wrong in this code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike pattern matches, regex matches aren't anchored to start/end of string, so a match *anywhere* in the string is enough. (It's more like "search" than "match", I think some Python function names make the distinction.) `ab_cdef` contain `ab_cd`, which matches.

You have to explicitly anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`:

```
$ if [[ foobar =~ o ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
$ if [[ foobar =~ ^o$ ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

---

Instead of `||` you could also put the alternation inside the regex:

```
re='^[a-z][a-z]_([0-9][0-9]|[a-z][a-z])$'
if [[ $host =~ $re ]]; then ...
```

(Or for a laxer regex allowing `ab_a0`: `^[a-z][a-z]_[0-9a-z][0-9a-z]$`.)

Comment: Thanks, it works! To check alphanumeric in a case like this where the hostnames could be `ab_01` or `ab_cd`, is `||` the best practice?

Can I combine the regex instead of using `||` ?

Comment: @Wolf, yeah, I was going to add a note on the alternative but had a brief network issue. See edit.

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu, your second update is very useful. It's good to know multiple ways to solve a problem